# I want to fetch some data from database on click of the link using jquery but on clicking link getting an alert with undefined type

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to get data from the database based on the text of that link on click of the link but getting undefined alert message.
I'm new to jquery so please help  me out with this if anybody can. Thanks in advance.
here is the code snippet

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name;
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=Menu] td a").click(function () {
            name=$(this).text().trim();
            GetRecords();
            //alert(name);
        });
    });
    function GetRecords() {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "kioskstore.aspx/GetPrice",
            data: '{name: ' + name + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var productsInfo = xml.find("Products_Info");
        productsInfo.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);

            $(".price").html(customer.find("Products_Price").text().trim());

        });
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
</script>
```

asp.net

```
<div style="margin-top:25px;height:40px;float: left;margin-left:40px;font-family:cursive;font-size:24px;color:#ffe476;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="price" Text=""></asp:Label>
 </div>
```

and the code behind C#

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string GetPrice(string name)
{
    return GetPriceData(name).GetXml();
}
public static DataSet GetPriceData(string name)
{
    string query = "select * from Product_Info where Product_Name=@pname";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", name);
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@PageCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    return GetData(cmd);
}
private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds, "Product_Info");
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing enclosing quotes for string.

Use

```
data: '{name: "' + name + '"}'
```

instead of

```
data: '{name: ' + name + '}'
```

Responding to your comment:
That message means you are requesting an incorrect URL. Please try with this.

```
url:document.location + '/GetPrice'
```

Please confirm whether your request is going to the correct URL. You can use the network monitor component of a browser development tools or an HTTP proxy like Fiddler. If you have chrome, you can check this using the Network tab of the Development Tools. Additionally you can make use of a chrome plugin called Postman to invoke HTTP request to check if they are working or not.

if you are calling from the same page?

Comment: Can you please add the following line as the first line in the error callback and let me know what the alert says?   alert(response.responseText);

Comment: I'm getting an alert with a huge amount of content in it starting from <doctype><title>unknown method kioskstore.aspx/getprice</title> blah.....

Comment: i'm getting this in alert                                        <h2> <i>Unknown web method kioskstore.aspx/GetPrice.<br>Parameter name: methodName</i> </h2></span>



            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">



            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.